# Dynamics Crm Invoking Workflow from external source

Tags: javascript, rest, controller, dynamics-crm, workflow

Scenario:

I would like to invoke an already defined workflow or a custom action from a web page which is located outside the CRM Dynamics context. (Let's say MS CRM 2011-2013-2015-2016 and 365)

My solution:

My idea would be about defining a kind of controller page into the CRM context accessible from the web and execute the rest call within that page (through javascript).
This page will be able to read input parameters and execute the right rest call.

Does it make sense? Could you suggest a better implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could carry out a test implementing your solution

Answer (score 1):

If you have the resources, you can setup a service utilizing the following methods and then ajax it.

```
private static void ExecuteWorkflow(Guid workflowId, Guid entityId)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crm"].ConnectionString;
            ClientCredentials cc = new ClientCredentials();
            cc.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            OrganizationServiceProxy _service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(url), null, cc, null);

            ExecuteWorkflowRequest request = new ExecuteWorkflowRequest()
            {
                WorkflowId = workflowId,
                EntityId = entityId
            };

            ExecuteWorkflowResponse r = (ExecuteWorkflowResponse)_service.Execute(request);
            _service.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle Exception
        }
    }
```

If you're unable to have the service on the same domain as the CRM server, you should be able to impersonate.

```
cc.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "DOMAIN";
cc.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "PASSWORD";
cc.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "USERNAME";
```

You can find more details here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.executeworkflowrequest.aspx

Comment: I know this method but doesn't help in my scenario. Imagine there's a website www.mywebsite.com. Within this web site i have js function that want to invoke a workflow on the crm www.dynamicscrm.com.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention.  This would have to be setup as a service.  You could then call that service.

Comment: Oh ok...and what about the user authentication? The workflow will be executed on behalf of who?

Comment: Is your CRM deployment and aforementioned website on separate domains?

Comment: Yeah they're independent...different infrastructure different locations..

Comment: I've never worked outside of the same domain before but you can always try impersonation.  See my edit above.  Unfortunately I don't have an environment setup like that to where I could test.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a workflow in a js like this:

You can query the workflowId by its name and the type definition.

```
    var entityId = // The GUID of the entity
    var workflowId = // The GUID of the workflow
    var url = // Your organization root
    var orgServicePath = "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
    url = url + orgServicePath;
    var request;
    request = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "<s:Body>" +
        "<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
        "<request i:type=\"b:ExecuteWorkflowRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">" +
        "<a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">" +
        "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
        "<c:key>EntityId</c:key>" +
        "<c:value i:type=\"d:guid\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">" + entityId + "</c:value>" +
        "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
        "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
        "<c:key>WorkflowId</c:key>" +
        "<c:value i:type=\"d:guid\" xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">" + workflowId + "</c:value>" +
        "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
        "</a:Parameters>" +
        "<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />" +
        "<a:RequestName>ExecuteWorkflow</a:RequestName>" +
        "</request>" +
        "</Execute>" +
        "</s:Body>" +
        "</s:Envelope>";

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, false);
    // Responses will return XML. It isn't possible to return JSON.
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
    req.send(request);
```

If the request.status is 200 the request was succesfull. This was tested on an CRM2011 enviroment.

I recommend you to create a **WCF rest or web api**, reference the IOrganizationService and from that use the operation of the CRM service. It is better to call a intermediate WCF than the IOrganizationService directly.